# How to add comments section to php website

Tags: php, mysql, comments

Hey guys, I have a website that has a url that looks sorta like this:
www.domain.com/photos.php?id=(image id);
Now, my question is, how can I add comments to each picture using mysql and php.

Comment: Would the comments be from users or one comment per picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably want a new table to link the user with the comment with the picture:

table: **comments**

```
id (comment id), user (user id), picture (pic id), comment (text), date(timestamp w/default current time)
```

Then after you show the image, do another query for any comments:

```
$comments_query = mysql_query("SELECT comment FROM comments WHERE picture = $id");
while($comments_result = mysql_fetch_array($comments_query)){
   echo($comments_result['comment']);
}
```

---

You will also probably want to link each user's username to the comment as well:

```
$comments_query = mysql_query("SELECT comments.comment, users.username, comments.date FROM comments INNER JOIN users ON comments.user = users.id WHERE comments.picture = $id");
while($comments_result = mysql_fetch_array($comments_query)){
    echo($comments_result['date']);
    echo($comments_result['username']);       
    echo($comments_result['comment']);
}
```